# Groovy How to use groupby to collection data

Tags: groovy

I have a requirment to convert a List formart :

```
def a = [ [ "BU": "A101", "Order No": "1", "Line No":"1", "Item No": "OT275"  ], [ "BU": "A101", "Order No": "1", "Line No":"2", "Item No": "OT277" ], ["BU": "A102", "Order No": "2", "Line No":"1", "Item No": "OT278" ]];
```

I use the `groupby()` to collect the data

```
def b = a.groupBy({it."BU"},{it."Order No"});
println(b)
```

The output is:

```
[A101:[1:[[BU:A101, Order No:1, Line No:1, Item No:OT275 ], [BU:A101, Order No:1, Line No:2, Item No:OT277 ]]], A102:[2:[[BU:A102, Order No:2, Line No:1, Item No:OT278 ]]]]
```

It's not my want format as below

```
[
    [
        "BU": "A101",
        "Order No": "1",
        "Detail": [
            [
                "Line No": "1",
                "Item No": "OT275" 
            ],
            [
                "Line No": "2",
                "Item No": "OT277" 
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "BU": "A102",
        "Order No": "2",
        "Detail": [
            [
                "Line No": "1",
                "Item No": "OT278" 
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

My Question: **How to use the List.groupby function to collect this format.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are:

- group by extracting a map with only the keys are interested (`BU`,
  `Order No`) for the groups with `subMap` (create a map, instead of the
  more common list here, because we can re-use the map for the result)
- then transform the result: it's a map with maps as keys and a list of
  all line items

  - for each key: add a new kew key `Details` to the "key" (the result
    map) and collect from the value (the list of line items) the
    `subMap` you are interested in (`Line No`, `Item No`) as value for
    `Details`; return the now modified "key"

E.g.

```
Collection<Map> group(Collection<String> groupingKeys, String detailsKey, Collection<String> detailKeys, Collection source) {
    source.groupBy{ 
        it.subMap groupingKeys
    }.collect{ k, v ->
        k + [(detailsKey): v.collect{ it.subMap detailKeys }]
    }
}

def a = [ [ "BU": "A101", "Order No": "1", "Line No":"1", "Item No": "OT275"  ], [ "BU": "A101", "Order No": "1", "Line No":"2", "Item No": "OT277" ], ["BU": "A102", "Order No": "2", "Line No":"1", "Item No": "OT278" ]];
println group(["BU", "Order No"], "Details", ["Line No", "Item No"], a)
// → [[BU:A101, Order No:1, Details:[[Line No:1, Item No:OT275], [Line No:2, Item No:OT277]]], [BU:A102, Order No:2, Details:[[Line No:1, Item No:OT278]]]]
```

Note: you can calculate the `detailKeys` by subtracting the
`groupingKeys` from the keyset of one of your items in case you just want all the non-grouping keys.

The problem with your attempt:

`groupBy` with multiple extractors will create you a nested map.  This
is useful, but you want just one level.  So you would have to write
*one* key extractor, that just returns your top level.  E.g. things like
`a.groupBy{ [it['BU'], it['Order No']] }` would work.  After that, it's
just a matter of shaping the result.

Comment: `Error message`:No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.tap() is applicable for argument types: (main$_group_closure2$_closure3) values: [main$_group_closure2$_closure3@2b662a77]
Possible solutions: max(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), wait(), any(), grep(), dump()

Comment: I replaced tap with just addition of the maps

Comment: For the record: the tap version will not work with Groovy <= 2.4, but is a little bit more efficient